# How to expose a filter of an list (text) field to your site visitors in a REST Export View

Tags: views, 9

How can I filter based on selections of a list (text) field and share that with users? For text fields this works out of the box, but for list fields you can only select the specified values:

[image: Views Screenshot]

I would like to be able to query the values as with the text fields also over a url like this:

```
https://mysite.com/api?search_categogy=reparaturen
```

ideally with operators like "contains".
how to do that?